# Fragment disappears after setAdapter on ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, baseadapter

I have a ListView in a Fragment containing also some other UI-Elements. Everything works until I call setAdapter on the ListView. In that moment I can debug that the ListView is filled with the elements but immmediately after the whole fragment disappears (including the other UI-Elements). If I set the Adapter 0,1 seconds later, everything works.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listview, null);
    mListView = (ListView)mView.findViewById(R.id.list_items);

    TextView emptyView = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.text_empty);
    mListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // this is the only work around to not make the list view disappear
            loadContacts();
        }
    }, 100);
    // if I call loadContacts() here, the Fragment disappears

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Person p = mContacts.get(position);
            if (pickerInterface != null) {
                pickerInterface.pickedContact(p);
            }
        }
    });
    return mView;
}


public void loadContacts() {
    mContacts = ContactsDataSource.getAllPhoneContacts(getActivity(), true);
    mAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(getActivity());
    mAdapter.mContacts = mContacts;
    mAdapter.isPlainList = true;
    // after the following line the Fragment is filled and then immediately disappears
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

the ContactsAdapter is very simple:

```
public class ContactsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public List<Person> mContacts = new ArrayList<Person>();
    public Activity context;

    // Constructor
    public ContactsAdapter(Activity c){
        context = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mContacts.size();
    }

    public Person getItem(int position){
        return mContacts.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return mContacts.size() == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_contact, null);
        }
        Person person = mContacts.get(position);

        TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_name);
        tvName.setText(person.getDisplayName());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

I have spent hours debugging and searching for reasons and have no clue. Thanks for any idea.

**Edit:** XML as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_items"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/line_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/label_no_entries"
        android:textColor="@color/grey"
        android:textSize="21sp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layout_navigation"
        android:background="@color/black" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_scrollback"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/backward"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:text="@string/activity_contacts_backward_label"
            android:textColor="@color/mediumgrey" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_coverback"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/text_scrollback"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/text_scrollback"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/text_scrollback"
            android:background="#c0ffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_scrollforward"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/forward"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:text="@string/activity_contacts_forward_label"
            android:textColor="@color/mediumgrey" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_coverforward"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/text_scrollforward"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text_scrollforward"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/text_scrollforward"
            android:background="#c0ffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_pages"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/text_scrollforward"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/text_scrollforward"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_scrollback"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/mediumgrey"
            android:textSize="17sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: u can put ur xml code...

Comment: I have added it above

Comment: Hard to guess, you'll need to post the full code. E.g. I don't see where you get mListView? If you are directly extending Fragment that super call does nothing etc ... without code that reproduces the behaviour mentioned, this is just going to be wild guessing.

Comment: Sorry, I should have pasted this part too. The SuperClass is also a custom class just initilizing a standard Layout I am using in other Fragments as well. Everything is done in onCreateView. I have changed the code above accordingly.

Comment: @Christian, U have set match_parent to width and height right. When the list is empty, ur able to see the other content but when ur list is updated, it occupied ur full view. Just for check add layout_below="@+id/layout_navigation" in listview .

Comment: @HarshaVardhan thanks, but I have set a horizontal line with layout_above. The list also works fine if I call the setAdapter after the delay.

Comment: @Christian, Check my answer given below. I am able to run ur code without any problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your support. By removing all code and re-assembling step by step I foundt the reason. Just in case someone runs in the same problem one day.

I had an `OnScrollListener` on the `ListView` declared in the superclass. In the OnScrollListener I was hiding the navigation Arrows on demand with Visibility.GONE. Even if the NavigationArrows did not affect the layout of the ListView this was the problem. By setting Visibility.INVISIBLE everything works fine. I guess this is related to some re-drawing-issue of the whole layout that does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you initialize your "mListView"?
The time that fragment inflated is "onCreateView()" and general way of getting view instances from layout is done on this method. like below

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, null);
  mListView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_items);
  ...
  return v;
}
```

How about trying to initalize your views(ListViews, and others) in "onCreateView"? 
I think that the problem is caused from getting view instances before fragment is inflated.

Comment: Yes I did it in the custom super class. Sorry for not including this part of the code. I have changed my code above.

Comment: valid to mention, but was not the reason, see my answer, but at least an upvote from my side

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your problem is. May be with the custom super class.  Otherwise, wild guess here, but try inflating your view like this.

```
mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listview, container, false);
```

Comment: it was not the reason (see my answer below), but thanks for the help and at least an upvote for the valid action

Answer (score 0):

First of all, storing a context object can be dangerous and should therefore be avoided if possible... You can easily get rid of it in your adapter with following steps (that hopefully also solves your problem):

--> try following constructor for your adapter:

```
public ContactsAdapter(Context c){
    super(c, R.layout.yourlayout_listitem_name;
}
```

--> and adjust the getView-method to use something like:

```
final View rowView = View.inflate(viewGroup.getContext(), R.layout.yourlayout_listitem_name, null);
```

instead of the inflater-if-block. then always **return rowView** at the end.

and just to be sure I would remove the overriden-method:

```
 @Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

since it is not doing anything useful anyway ;-)

Comment: Thank you, I tried what you mentioned, but same result. I changed `BaseAdapter` to `ArrayAdapter` (as BaseAdapter does not have `super(Context, int)`. With your `getView`-method I would inflate a view each time `getView`? is called or not? Anyway after the changes again the Fragment disappears completely after `setAdapter()`

Comment: if you are working in a Fragment, have you tried another hook yet? like **onViewCreated**

Comment: yes, I tried onResume and onStart, onViewCreated is not possible, I have to support API-Level 9

Comment: Don't switch to `ArrayAdapter` you were correct in keeping with `BaseAdapter`. It's perfectly fine to store the `Context` within the adapter because the adapter's lifespan will die with the Activity.  Keep the if block. You don't want to re-inflate a view with every `getView` call